# How to use exact node in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

i am very new react..
Someone suggected to use exact node rather than entire object, like in this case name. I also struggling with async behavior.

```
@connect(state => ({ 
   user_name: state.user.name,
   last_message: state.messages[state.messages.length-1]
}))
```

I dispatch a action under componentDidmount to load my initial data, But my user data takes time to load through API.
When i try `user_name: state.user.name` in the connect portion , i get a undefined property error as data is still being fetched and code breaks.
TO overcome this is use: `user_name: state.user` and try to access name through next props.
Am I doing this right.

How to properly load API data. I am using redux and thunk with axios.

Answer (score 0):

not necessarily best practice, but you could add a conditional...

```
@connect(state => ({ 
   // check if the data is done loading
   if (state.user.name) {
     return {
     user_name: state.user.name,
     last_message: state.messages[state.messages.length-1]
     valid: true
     }
   }
   else return {
    valid: false 
   }
}))
```

Then inside the component you're rendering, you can add a flag at the top, something like

```
if (!props.valid) {
  return <Loading />
}

return (
...
)
```

Comment: what should i follow as a practice...is defining initial state in reducer solve this... i doubt this..
can I use promise to load the request n then proceed..

Answer (score 0):

You simply can put a condition to check whether user exits and then access the name from it as

```
@connect(state => ({ 
   user_name: state.user && state.user.name,
   last_message: state.messages[state.messages.length-1]
}))
```

Now in your code you will be able to access the `user_name` which gives you `undefined` if user was not defined so as long as you are not trying to get another object from `user_name`, it should be OK. However you can check for the `undefined` value in the component.

Comment: should I define the object in my initial sate object...in reducer